# Explain generated file from wsdl in java

Tags: java, web-services, wsdl

I generated java client based on a WSDL file

there are some class 'CustomerServiceServiceStub' , 'CustomerServiceServiceCallbackHandler'

what are these ?

and how can i understand all method witch this service expose to me, i want to write a document that explain this web service and it's methods and exceptions.

What should i do ?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of looking for answers in the generated classes, you should be referring to the wsdl. A wsdl provides the web service contract details like what parameters it expects, what output it will give, name of the service method etc. Then if you look into your generated classes, you will be able to connect the dots and understand what the class is supposed to do.